# Empty array when selecting posts from the category

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get all posts in certain category, but I'm getting empty array.
Here is my code:

```
$posts_args = array(
  'numberposts' => 6,
  'category' => 14,
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'post_type' => 'post'
);
$posts_array = get_posts($posts_args);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($posts_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

But in admin panel displaying properly.

Comment: is it a custom post type category or default category of post section ?

Comment: It is custom post type category.

Comment: Where is you `get_posts` method? What is it doing?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
         $posts_args=array( 
                   'posts_per_page' => 6,
                   'post_type' => 'post',  
                   'order'   => 'DESC',  
                     'tax_query' => array(
                      array(
                          'taxonomy' => 'category',
                          'field'    => 'term_id',
                          'terms'    => array( 14),                           
                         ),
                      )
             );
           $posts_array = get_posts($posts_args);

           echo "<pre>";
           print_r($posts_array);
           echo "</pre>";
```